# Move disabled products to the end of the catalog product list

Tags: magento-1.9

"Hi,

I need to push disabled products to the end of catalog list
Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Example: All enabled products at top but disabled products at bottom.

Comment: on frontend is not possible since disabled means they don't show on the website.

Comment: I want to display magento backend not frontend.

Comment: I am using merchandising extension in this extension I want to display all disables products at bottom in backend.

Comment: As per given code please guide me how  to add code for displaying all disabled products at bottom in backend.
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('report_table_views' =>'report_event'),'e.entity_id=report_table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4',
array('e.*','COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS views'))
->group('e.entity_id')
->order('views DESC');

Answer (score 0):

if you have a product collection called `$productCollection` you can sort by status like this:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('status', 'ASC');
```

This is all I could do with the details you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything, simply open your product listing page.You can see various tab there like id, name type etc. exactly on right side you will see Status simply click on it. you product will listed as status.